# Fluent Nhibernate Optimistick locking not working

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, optimistic-locking

In my application I have set the application to use the strategy to prevent 2 different conversations to work at the same data. But is not working, I don't know why.

PROBLEM:

```
1) User1: 
Retrive rowversion from database: 0x00000000001063B0
Do some modification
2) User2:
Retrive rowversion from database: 0x00000000001063B0
Do some modification
3) User1:
Update the data
New rowversion: 0x00000000001063B2
4) User2:
Update the data
Should trown a StaleObjectStateException, 
but the rowversion is updated to 0x00000000001063B4
```

CONFIGURATION:

I have in my application the Fluent Nhibernate configuration:

```
public static ClassMap<T> RowVersionTracking<T>(this ClassMap<T> classMap) where T : DomainObject
    {
        classMap.OptimisticLock.Version();

        classMap
            .Version(x => x.RowVersion)
            .Column(DomainObject.VersionPropertyName)
            .CustomType("BinaryBlob")
            .CustomSqlType("timestamp")
            .Generated.Always()
            .UnsavedValue("null");


        return classMap;
    }
```

And when I save for example, an instance of CustomerOrder that inherits this property:

Has in the mappings:

```
...
   this.RowVersionTracking();
...
```

best regards,
Tito

Comment: how does the sql-update of user2 looks like? there must be the `Where rowversion = '0x00000000001063B0'` in there

Comment: You should verify your extension method is generating the correct mapping. Look at [this post](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/19/how-to-configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate) to configure NHibernate to output configuration information to a log. Set the `level value="ALL"` to see the actual HBM XML Fluent NHibernate is creating. Run your test and check the log for the CustomerOrder mapping. Make sure its HBM XML class element contains the attribute `optimistic-lock="version"` and has a child element `version name="RowVersion" ...`